# Can you extracting a specific string of text from a long varchar in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a syslog server that inputs its events into a SQL Server database as a `varchar`. The data looks something like this

```
Apr 27 22:03:38 ServerName MSWinEventLog 3 Application 4217 Thu Apr 27 22:03:30 2017 1009 MSExchangeHM  N/A Error ServerName 2 Microsoft Exchange Health ...
```

I am trying to do a count or the number of times any unique error ID comes up. The error ID is always proceeded by "2017" in this case the code is 1009. I am trying to find a way to do a search on that code, or output the 7 lines following the first instance of " 2017 " in the `varchar`.

I am very new the SQL and there is a good change I am missing some knowledge that would make this easier, but this is my approach, so far.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT([key]) AS CountofErrors,
    MAX(MSGTEXT) AS FULLMessage,
    CASE
       WHEN (CASE 
                WHEN LEFT(RIGHT(MSGTEXT, LEN(MSGTEXT) - 51), 12) LIKE 'a%'
                   THEN LEFT(RIGHT(MSGTEXT, LEN(MSGTEXT) - 51), 11)
                   ELSE RIGHT(LEFT(RIGHT(MSGTEXT, LEN(MSGTEXT) - 51), 12), 11) 
             END) LIKE 's%'
          THEN LEFT(LEFT(RIGHT(MSGTEXT, LEN(MSGTEXT) - 52), 12), 6)  
          ELSE (CASE
                   WHEN LEFT(RIGHT(MSGTEXT, LEN(MSGTEXT) - 51), 12) LIKE 'a%'
                      THEN LEFT(RIGHT(MSGTEXT, LEN(MSGTEXT) - 51), 11)
                      ELSE RIGHT(LEFT(RIGHT(MSGTEXT, LEN(MSGTEXT) - 51), 12), 11) 
                END) 
       END AS system2
FROM 
    SyslogDatabase
WHERE
    ...
GROUP BY
    ...
```

This finds out if a event is an application error or a system error because this dictates how many more characters there will be until the event ID. I can see this getting very messy from this point forward because following the application or system is a number that can be 1 to 5 digits long. I am hoping there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
create table t (id int not null identity(1,1), msgtext varchar(8000))
insert into t values 
('Apr 27 22:03:38 ServerName MSWinEventLog 3 Application 4217 Thu Apr 27 22:03:30 
 2017 1009 MSExchangeHM  N/A Error ServerName 2 Microsoft Exchange Health ...
 2017 1009 MSExchangeHM  N/A Error ServerName 2 Microsoft Exchange Health ...
 2017 1010 MSExchangeHM  N/A Error ServerName 2 Microsoft Exchange Health ...')

select 
    t.id
  , s.ItemNumber
  , ErrorId = left(s.Item,charindex(' ',s.Item+' ')-1)
  , s.Item
from t
  cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8k(replace(t.msgtext,'2017 ',char(30)),char(30)) s
where s.Item like '[0-9]%'
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/LVS48443

returns:

```
+----+------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | ItemNumber | ErrorId |                                  Item                                   |
+----+------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |          2 |    1009 | 1009 MSExchangeHM  N/A Error ServerName 2 Microsoft Exchange Health ... |
|  1 |          3 |    1009 | 1009 MSExchangeHM  N/A Error ServerName 2 Microsoft Exchange Health ... |
|  1 |          4 |    1010 | 1010 MSExchangeHM  N/A Error ServerName 2 Microsoft Exchange Health ... |
+----+------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

---

If you need to support `varchar(max)` input up to a million characters (this modification reduces performance), you can use an alternate by Aaron Bertrand (with `ItemNumber` added back in) or other string splitting options in the references above:

```
create function dbo.SplitStrings_Moden (@list varchar(max), @delimiter varchar(255))
returns table with schemabinding as return
  with e1(n)        as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 
                         union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 
                         union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1),
       e2(n)        as (select 1 from e1 a, e1 b),
       e4(n)        as (select 1 from e2 a, e2 b),
       e42(n)       as (select 1 from e4 a, e2 b),
       ctetally(n)  as (select 0 union all select top (datalength(isnull(@list,1))) 
                         row_number() over (order by (select null)) from e42),
       ctestart(n1) as (select t.n+1 from ctetally t
                         where (substring(@list,t.n,1) = @delimiter or t.n = 0))
  select 
      ItemNumber = row_number() over(order by s.n1)
    , Item = substring(@list, s.n1, isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter,@list,s.n1),0)-s.n1,8000))
  from ctestart s;
go
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it working with your suggestion. For some reason I could not get the results properly when I searched for ' 2007 ' , but I got it working when I searched for the month. I guess I have to understand a bit more how this delimitedsplit8K function works before I can figure out why it was not working perfectly.

Comment: @J.Johnson It depends on which function you used. The function I used for the rextester demo is the original version of `delimitedsplit8k` and the delimiter is limited to `char(1)`, which is why I am replacing the `2017` string with `char(30)`, and splitting on `char(30)` instead.  If you used the second function from the bottom of my answer (`SplitStrings_Moden`), that supports longer delimiters (`varchar(255)`). .

Answer (score 0):

**1- Let's first control the catching algorithm logic:


- we need to search for the format of "** **:**:** 2017" or whatever the current year. and catch the next number between the next to space places " 1009 "


- insert distinct of the collected err number in a table using a number per session (daily, hourly, or whatever the session definition).**


**2- Let us secondly think in simplify the code using alternative ways.**

 - Sql Cursor: 
read about it first, and Make stored procedure and program it to select each line and make string manipulation on it, in this case you got a feature of making String validation and any check you want on the selected text before you be sure of error numbers on it (by the ideas on the previous point).

 - Linq Lambda for string manipulation: 
 use the .net code to loop through the code and use .ToArray() or .ToList() to gather the results.

If i arranged some sample code for you I'll add it here sooner, but start read more about (Sql Cursor, Lambda expression and string manipulation) that will move you up very fast in most of your next tasks.